# How to import settings into CLion from Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, clion

I'm working with IntelliJ and I have the IDE configured to my needs. I'd like to transfer these settings to CLion.

Is this possible? If so, how?

On the official sites there is no info on that so I'm assuming I'd have to do it by hand (using the settings files and try my luck).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`File` | `Export Settings` in IntelliJ IDEA followed by `File` | `Import Settings` in CLion should do the trick.

Another option is to use the [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/settings-repository.html) for synchronization.

This option is [not available](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202548) when you are using settings sync with account or repository.

Comment: Settings Repository did the trick for me. It wasn't enabled by default in CLion.